# "A spatial equivalent station to" vs. "a spatial equivalent station as"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> The second working period shall either start at the same station or in a  spatial equivalent station **to** the first working period's start station.

I'm in doubt regarding the preposition *to* used above, because I kinda feel that the preposition *as* would also fit there. But I'm not sure which one to use or why use one instead of another.

Comment: *Equivalent* take the prep. *to*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collocation is *equivalent to*. I can't think of any context in which *equivalent as* would be used instead.

I'm not sure what the sentence is about, but it sounds very legalistic. Perhaps it's meant to, but, in any case, you probably need *spatially equivalent* rather than *spatial equivalent*.

Comment: By the way *spatial equivalent* could be fine -- 'a station that is  the spacial equivalent of another.'